# Better Design for a multi column search - Django PostgreSQL

Tags: django, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a table of products(**productsmaster**).
For each product in the table, I have four columns to show the months in which quarterly check dates are conducted (**product1: Q1-Jan, Q2-Apr; product2: Q1-Dec,Q2Mar...**)
I am developing an app in Django-PostgreSQL that for a specified month, it picks all products that are reporting in the specified month ie that have the month in column Q1 or Q2 or Q3 or Q4.
The products are set up once but are accessed a lot more when being read for reports and processing.  I am sorry I dont have any code yet as I am looking to clarify design before I start coding. Can anyone advise how I can improve this? Database design if possible but willing to use django solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a dedicated model for this, call it `ProductCheck`

```
product | quater | month
------------------------
 prod1  |   Q1   |  Jan
 prod1  |   Q2   |  Apr
 prod2  |   Q1   |  Dec
 prod2  |   Q2   |  Mar
```

Then your query looks like this:

```
ProductCheck.objects.filter(month="Jan")
```

Remember to put indexes on the fields that are most commonly searched upon, to speed up the query. Also you can add unique constraint to avoid duplicated data.